# add spesific attribute to anchor tag in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problem while create menu in `wordpress`

Nav code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
  <ul id="mobile" class="sidenav">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current- 
     menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-7"> <a href="http://localhost/test/">Home</a> </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13"> <a href="http://localhost/buildownwp/laman-contoh/">Laman Contoh</a> </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1159"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">et nulam</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-15"> <a href="http://localhost/buildownwp/tak-berkategori/halo-dunia/" class="dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Halo dunia!</a> </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1161"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">second2</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-14"> <a href="http://localhost/buildownwp/tak-berkategori/lorem-ipsum/" class="dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Lorem Ipsum</a> </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1160"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">second</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1158"> <a href="#">dolor sit amet</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

jQuery

```
$('.menu-item-has-children a').attr('class', 'dropdown-toggle').attr('id','navbarDropdown').attr('data-toggle','dropdown').attr('aria-haspopup','true').attr('aria-expanded','false');
```

that code should be display like a menu if have `class`  `menu-item-has-children` will adding attribut or like a multiple dropdown if that menu have a dropdown but the result that code like this [image: nav-mobile]

submenu hello,lorem ipsum and second , should not affected that code , couse he not have child menu / submenu  , many thank if you can help me

Comment: I guess this method is adding '.dropdown-toggle' class to every child anchor tags of '.menu-item-has-children', but you want to limit it only to one parent anchor tag? right?

Comment: nah thats right buddy, i just want limit adding attribute just 1 after `menu-item-has-children`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , I know you want limit find anchor tag just on parent right?
your code

```
$('.menu-item-has-children a').attr('class', 'dropdown-toggle').attr('id','navbarDropdown').attr('data-toggle','dropdown').attr('aria-haspopup','true').attr('aria-expanded','false');
```

change `$('.menu-item-has-children a')` with `$('.menu-item-has-children > a')`

like this

```
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').attr('class', 'dropdown-toggle').attr('id','navbarDropdown').attr('data-toggle','dropdown').attr('aria-haspopup','true').attr('aria-expanded','false');
```